# Bash to read file and get keyvalue pair split by spaces

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a text file and split it's defined content as a key value pair.
Content are multiple lines with key&value. Where key wont have spaces, so first space splits the key and value. but the value may have single or multiple or leading and trailing spaces. My scripts works fine with one flaw, that it removes all multi spaces. I want my value exactly how it mentioned in the file.

core script:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./inp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    parts=($line)
    key=${parts[0]}
    value=${parts[@]:1:${#parts[@]}}
    echo .
    echo "Key: [$key]"
    echo "Value: [$value]"
    echo .
done < "$input"
```

input file (inp.txt):

```
KEY1 VAL1
KEY2   VAL2 has space & multi  spaces &    leading & trailing spaces.  
KEY3 VAL3
KEY4 VAL4
KEY5 VAL5
```

output:

```
Key: [KEY1]
Value: [VAL1]
.
.
Key: [KEY2]
Value: [VAL2 has space & multi spaces & leading & trailing spaces.]
.
.
Key: [KEY3]
Value: [VAL3]
.
.
Key: [KEY4]
Value: [VAL4]
.
.
Key: [KEY5]
Value: [VAL5]
```

expected: (Check KEY2-VALUE2)

```
Key: [KEY1]
Value: [VAL1]
.
.
Key: [KEY2]
Value: [  VAL2 has space & multi  spaces &    leading & trailing spaces.  ]
.
.
Key: [KEY3]
Value: [VAL3]
.
.
Key: [KEY4]
Value: [VAL4]
.
.
Key: [KEY5]
Value: [VAL5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use standard POSIX parameter expansions `${parameter%%word}` to remove the longest trailing substring and `${parameter#word}` to remove the shortest leading substring:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./inp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    key=${line%% *}
    value=${line#* }
    echo .
    echo "Key: [$key]"
    echo "Value: [$value]"
    echo .
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` on `$line` to delete `KEY`, its number and the first space instead of outputting each element of `$parts`:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./inp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    parts=($line)
    key=${parts[0]}
    value=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/KEY[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]//')
    echo .
    echo "Key: [$key]"
    echo "Value: [$value]"
    echo .
done < "$input"
```

Comment: For example only, i made key names ending with number. But in actual requriement, it might be a simple KEY with out a number. So I need to relay on first space only. to split the Key and rest all values.

Comment: The regular expression will still match on a KEY without a number since the `*` token matches zero or more digits.

Comment: A simpler and more flexible regex operation might be: `sed 's/^[^ ]* //'` - "beginning of line"+"zero or more occurrences of any character but a space"+"space".